# Shape's stroke doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shape

I defined a `Drawable` with a stroke but the stroke does not appear on the UI.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/otherSecurityLaneImageView"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    tools:src="@drawable/poi_icon_security_lane_clear" />
```

Here's how `@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp` is defined:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="20dp" android:color="@color/ll_red" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

I expected to see a fat red border around the `ImageView` in the Android Studio design view but none appears.

Answer (score 3):

You can use various combinations:

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
```

ll_rounded_corners_6dp.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="20dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</shape>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code. Your drawable code is fine.

But to show stroke, There are need some changes in layoit xml code,

Just remove `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"` because of background tint color stroke does not appear, the main cause of it is that `backgroundTint` set the color into background of ImageView.

If you need to use `backgroundTint` you can use same color as stroke color.

Please try below code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/otherSecurityLaneImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ll_rounded_corners_6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I hope its working for you.

Comment: Thanks, if you have a link to documentation that explains why `android:backgroundTint` conflicts with `stroke`, that would be great info to include here.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I got the `stroke` to appear by removing the `android:backgroundTint` parameter from the `ImageView`.  I could not find documentation about it.  I also tried different `android:tintMode`s but none of them helped.